# Universal Image Loader Android : Changing Layout properties causes OutOfMemoryError

Tags: android, android-layout, universal-image-loader

I have multiple activity. Each activity shows images in a GridView. Each activity as an standalone application works fine. The problem occurs when i call an activity from another one.
An item of GridView(second/third activities) is an imageView :

```
 <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/grid_sub_item_image"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/descr_image"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" >
    </ImageView>
```

When I set width, height in dp/px it works well.LIke:

```
android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
```

Works fine for me.

But when I set height/width : wrap_content/fill_parent, its getting Out of Memory exception:

```
null
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeStream(Native Method)
android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:493)
com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.ImageDecoder.decode(ImageDecoder.java:83)
com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.LoadAndDisplayImageTask.decodeWithOOMHandling(LoadAndDisplayImageTask.java:187)
com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.LoadAndDisplayImageTask.decodeImage(LoadAndDisplayImageTask.java:170)
com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.LoadAndDisplayImageTask.tryLoadBitmap(LoadAndDisplayImageTask.java:126)
com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.LoadAndDisplayImageTask.run(LoadAndDisplayImageTask.java:72)
java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:442)
java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

I have instantiated ImageLoader at every Activity. But it does not help.

Comment: Did you read Readme - https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader#useful-info?

Comment: what is size of your image ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Useful Info section](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader#useful-info) describes how UIL downscales original image and what parameters are used for it.

So I recommend you to set `android:maxWidth` and `android:maxHeight` parameters for your ImageView to save memory.

Comment: I have set height and width of the ImageView on run-time, by calculating device resolution. it works :)